# Django admin looks fine, untill I open category. Then overlapping

Tags: django

I have a pretty basic django install, with summernote.

When I'm in the admin panel, it looks like so.
[image: normal]
But when I go to any of the category pages, it looks like this.
[image]
I tried clearing cache, but still looks the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
My models code is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
import uuid

STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts"
    )
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse

        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"slug": str(self.slug)})

    def get_previous_by_created_on_active(self):
        return self.get_previous_by_created_on(status=1)

    def get_next_by_created_on_active(self):
        return self.get_next_by_created_on(status=1)

class Newsletter(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=200, unique=True)
    conf_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email + " (" + ("not " if not self.confirmed else "") + "confirmed)"
```

Comment: could you post the models code

Comment: Try to hard reload **Ctrl+Shift+R**

Comment: @THUNDER07 update question with models.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari tried that to no avail

Comment: @nadermx could you try commenting each field and reloading , to figure weather the field is causing the trouble....

Comment: @THUNDER07 I'm unsure what happened.   But I grabbed the admin files from another django project, and put them in.  And it loads fine now after the hard reset.  So maybe a file was in cache? or corrupt? unsure.  Either way, it's fixed now.  Thanks.

Comment: @THUNDER07 if you wish to post the hard reset as the solution, once I set the new admin files, that fixed the layout.

Comment: @nadermx nothanks I am glad its ok now

Answer (score 0):

I see you got the solution.
I suggest providing the display in admin view correctly and as you want.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import YourModel


@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "slug") // fields you want to display
```